# Почему return не возвращает значение переменных?

Tags: python, return

Есть программа, которая проверяет входные данные и выводит на экран результат арифметической операции. Вторая функция не возвращает значения переменных. Почему?

```py
def check_input(num_1, num_2, operation):
    while not num_1.isdigit():
        num_1 = input('Будьте внимательны! Введите первое число еще раз: ')
    while not num_2.isdigit():
        num_2 = input('Будьте внимательны! Введите второе число еще раз: ')
    while operation != '+' and operation != '-' and operation != '/' and operation != '*':
        operation = input('Будьте внимательны! Какую операцию необходимо провести. Введите + * - /\n')
    return num_1, num_2, operation
```

Вот весь код:

```py
def math_operations():
    if operation == '+':
        print(num_1, operation, num_2, '=', int(num_1)+int(num_2))
    elif operation == '-':
        print(num_1, operation, num_2, '=', int(num_1)-int(num_2))
    elif operation == '/':
        print(num_1, operation, num_2, '=', int(num_1)/int(num_2))
    elif operation == '*':
        print(num_1, operation, num_2, '=', int(num_1)*int(num_2))
        
def check_input(num_1, num_2, operation):
    while not num_1.isdigit():
        num_1 = input('Будьте внимательны! Введите первое число еще раз: ')
    while not num_2.isdigit():
        num_2 = input('Будьте внимательны! Введите второе число еще раз: ')
    while operation != '+' and operation != '-' and operation != '/' and operation != '*':
        operation = input('Будьте внимательны! Какую операцию необходимо провести. Введите + * - /\n')
    return num_1, num_2, operation
    
number_1 = input('Введите первое число: ')
number_2 = input('Введите второе число: ')
operat = input('Какую операцию необходимо провести. Введите + * - /\n')

check_input(number_1, number_2, operat)

print(f'''
Вы ввели:
- первое число: {num_1}
- второе число: {num_2}
- оператор: {operation}
''')

math_operations()
```

Comment: А что имеется в виду под *не возвращает*?

Comment: Добрый день. Добавь, пожалуйста, как именно ты призываешь `check_input`. Возможно ошибка там.

Comment: Все не правильно, зачем у функции параметры если ввод с клавиатуры, проверка перед вводом, последнее условие про операцию, если ввести например "," то все условия выполнятся, если ввести "+" , то три из четырех условий выполнятся, а стоит AND.

Comment: @wchistow дальше в коде идет обращение с переменным num_1, num_2, operation, но программа выдает ошибку, что таких переменных нет

Comment: @Gh0sTG0 вызываю в программе def math_operations():
'''number_1 = input('Введите первое число: ')
number_2 = input('Введите второе число: ')
operat = input('Какую операцию необходимо провести. Введите + * - /\n')

check_input(number_1, number_2, operat)'''

Comment: А за пределами этой функции таких переменных и нет.

Comment: @Oopss без функции все работает и условие выполняется. Ввод данных с клавиатуры происходит до вызова функции 'number_1 = input('Введите первое число: ')
number_2 = input('Введите второе число: ')
operat = input('Какую операцию необходимо провести. Введите + * - /\n')

check_input(number_1, number_2, operat)'

Comment: @Эникейщик есть, просто не пойму пока, как весь код добавить)))

Comment: Если вам выдаётся ошибка, что таких переменных нет, значит их нет, даже если вам кажется, что они есть. Переменные num_1, num_2, Operation вне вашей функции НЕ СУЩЕСТВУЮТ.

Comment: `number_1, number_2, operat = check_input(number1, ...` попробуй.

Comment: @Эникейщик это понятно, просто не понятно почему)

Comment: @Gh0sTG0 все заработало, спасибо, добрый человек. Чуть голова не сломалась). Если есть возможность, объясните, почему так)))

Comment: Потому что а) эти переменные существуют только внутри функции, б) вы возвращаемые переменные никуда не присваиваете, в) нужно внимательнее читать учебник.

Comment: @Эникейщик спасибо огромное за ответ. А вообще как вам такое решение этой задачи?

Answer (score 1):

Вы не записываете возвращаемое значение. Правильно вот так:

```
def math_operations():
    if operation == '+':
        print(num_1, operation, num_2, '=', int(num_1)+int(num_2))
    elif operation == '-':
        print(num_1, operation, num_2, '=', int(num_1)-int(num_2))
    elif operation == '/':
        print(num_1, operation, num_2, '=', int(num_1)/int(num_2))
    elif operation == '*':
        print(num_1, operation, num_2, '=', int(num_1)*int(num_2))
        
def check_input(num_1, num_2, operation):
    while not num_1.isdigit():
        num_1 = input('Будьте внимательны! Введите первое число еще раз: ')
    while not num_2.isdigit():
        num_2 = input('Будьте внимательны! Введите второе число еще раз: ')
    while operation != '+' and operation != '-' and operation != '/' and operation != '*':
        operation = input('Будьте внимательны! Какую операцию необходимо провести. Введите + * - /\n')
    return num_1, num_2, operation
    
number_1 = input('Введите первое число: ')
number_2 = input('Введите второе число: ')
operat = input('Какую операцию необходимо провести. Введите + * - /\n')

number_1, number_2, operation = check_input(number_1, number_2, operat)

print(f'''
Вы ввели:
- первое число: {number_1}
- второе число: {number_2}
- оператор: {operation}
''')

math_operations()
```

Почитайте про систему области видимости и изменяемые/неизменяемые переменные. Изучите вопрос указателей в Python.